# Can something be apparently X without actually being X?

Tags: single-word-requests

I mean, let's say a dog appears sick, but is in fact perfectly healthy. Could the dog be said to be *apparently* sick?

Comment: _It appears to be sick_ I would say

Comment: If you don't know the true state of affairs: _the dog appears/seems to be sick_. If you do: _the dog just looks sick – it's really perfectly healthy_. The normal usage of 'apparently' is as a modal pragmatic marker, conveying your / the speaker's assessment of the situation. This ties in with the first situation in this post, not the second. However, since such markers usually double as adverbs, it is often better to rephrase to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Or you could say *The dog only appears sick*.  This would convey you are aware of the sickly appearance, but you know him to be healthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[apparent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apparently) means readily seen; clear or obvious; evidently. It is used by speakers or writers to avoid committing themselves to the truth of what they are saying, but which they have evidence for.

The strength of the word apparent is too great to take it to mean something which is clearly not the case, but rather something that has not been *proven to be* the case.

> Justin Bieber turned up late to his concert because he was [apparently](http://www.ok.co.uk/celebrity-news/Justin-Bieber-late-to-concert-because-he-played-video-games-and-threw-a-tantrum) playing video games and throwing tantrums, not because of 'technical difficulties'.

If one found a man lying in the street, one would not say, "He is apparently quite drunk." That usage would not be correct, as one needs *some* support to use the word. If he smelled of alcohol, was lying down, slurring his speech, one could use the word. The *fact* (determined after investigation) might be that he had merely been drinking and sustained a stroke.

One could say, "He has apparently passed out," before checking his vital signs to find he is, in fact, dead. In that case, apparently fits well.

So, while in theory, you can say something is apparently so, only to be wrong, it would be a sub-optimal use of the word to represent something without any evidence of it's truth.